# What are Arcueid's origin similarities with Caster?

Tags: tsukihime, fate-extra

In the Rani route in Fate Extra I recently beat Arcueid Brunestud while playing as Caster.

At the end if you look in Berserker's matrix under details than under True Ancestor, at the very bottom it says "And on a totally unrelated note, the fox-eared Caster gets along very well with her as it is believed that they share the same basic origins."

I have looked at both of their origin stories and I fail to see those similarities. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could reveal the similarities that would have led to them getting along well with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arcueid is a True Ancestor which are incarnated nature spirits akin to the Elementals where the term “Elemental” usually refers to spirits born from nature.

The playable Caster in Fate/Extra was said to be the human form of Kitsune and is a bit higher than an Earth Spirit because her soul was created by Amaterasu as a unique facet of herself. Because of that she would be classified as an Elemental so in a sense they are both Elementals.

Playable Caster was created by Amaterasu who is the goddess of the Sun while True Ancestor were created by Brunestud of the Crimson Moon, the Ultimate One of the Moon. Now if you know Shinto religion, Tsukuyomi, God of the Moon is Amaterasu's brother thus making the Sun and Moon related. So Playable Caster is like a child of the sun while Arcueid is the Princess of the children of the moon. This is a weak connection as we know Amaterasu exists in the Nasuverse but we don't know to what extent Tsukuyomi exists and if he has any connection to Brunestud.